# ssh stuck after showing local version

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I am trying to ssh to a different system from my Ubuntu, but it got stuck after this log

```
root@akash:~# ssh -vvv root@192.168.2.219
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.2.219" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.219 [192.168.2.219] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
```

and after some time I got a connection time out.
I generated the new ssh RSA key via `ssh-keygen -t rsa` on both the machines then, I copied my public key from `id_rsa.pub` to the file `authorized_keys` of the remote machine and vice-a-versa.

Now, one machine can login easily but the other one can't.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you running this with `sudo`? 1. You are already root so `sudo` is pointless. 2. You are logging in as root remotely, there's no reason to use sudo for the ssh command. Is your key your regular user's key? If so, root won't be able to use it. Are you sure the remote machine allows you to connect as root? It really, really shouldn't. What key did you copy? From where? To where? What directory? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: @terdon Is it Ok Now or Or something still missing?

Comment: No, we need to know what users are involved. You didn't answer any of my questions about root, you didn't explain what `authorized_keys` file you used (what directory, which machine). We need to know what was copied where.

Comment: We created a file `authorized_keys` under .ssh folder.
Then, copied public key from `id_rsa.pub` file to `authorized_keys` file as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: You haven't told us *which* `.ssh` folder. `/root/.ssh`? `/home/akash/.ssh`? On which machine? Local or remote? And please ***[edit]*** your question to add this information. And, for the third time, explain why you are doing all this as root.

Comment: Did you look at your ssh server logfiles?